# What does put a floor under... mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean SAVE?

Governments and central banks have promised to shell out $19.5 trillion since the coronavirus erupted to "put a floor under the world economy," according to the International Monetary Fund. Some countries need even more help to recover from the crisis, but they might not get it.

Source: https://edition.cnn.com/2020/11/17/economy/global-economy-coronavirus-bailout-imf-annual-report/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metaphorically it means "prevent from dropping below a certain point".  So it is rather different from "save"